# how to setup robotdyn arduino mega+esp8266

Tags: html, robotics, arduino-esp8266

I am making a web server with a robotdyn arduino mega + esp8266  to control a few bo motors I flashed the firmware for the esp8266 I have 2 questions, 1: when I give AT commands through the serial monitor It doesn't respond also when I open the serial monitor its saying, "error opening COM4, port busy" how can I solve this? the second one is how can I embed the html code into the arduino code? by the way I didn't use any code for the AT commands. Can you also tell how I should orient the switches (they're only on the robotdyn arduino mega/uno + esp8266 model not on normal esp8266 chips)on the mega while talking the the mega?

Comment: scroll down this page for the switches https://robotdyn.com/mega-wifi-r3-atmega2560-esp8266-flash-32mb-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html

Comment: did you flash AT firmware to the esp8266?

Comment: your question is off-topic here on SO. yoiu should ask on Arduino SE

Comment: Is there a difference between normal firmware and "AT" firmware ?is there another firmware called AT firmware? if there is please tell me how I can flash the AT firmware .

Comment: there is no 'normal' firmware. https://blog.gabrielcsapo.com/arduino-web-server-mega-2560-r3-built-in-esp8266/